# Python Beautifulsoup remover tag dentro de tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

estou com um problema ao fazer um scrap de uma página e capturar o texto.

Basicamente o comeco do meu código é o seguinte:

```
url0 = 'https://www.service.bund.de/Content/DE/Ausschreibungen/Suche/Formular.html?nn=4641482&cl2Addresses_Adresse_State=nordrhein-westfalen&resultsPerPage=100'

r = requests.get(url0,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('ul', {"class": "result-list"})
links = content.find_all('a')
```

Cada linha da tabela do site que eu estou tentando buscar é um elemento da lista "links". Pois bem, ai eu quero tirar a primeira coluna (Ausschreibung) que está dentro da tag h3 dentro de cada elemento da lista links. Só que essa tag tem uma segunda tag  embutida:

```
# Usando um exemplo de elemento links:
y = links[0]

b = y.find('h3')
b
# output: '<h3><em>Ausschreibung</em>Er­neue­rung SDRL 3</h3>'
```

O problema é que quando eu vou pegar o texto dessas tags a minha máquina (Windows 10) está "lendo" também a tag e traduzindo tudo errado:

```
c = y.find('h3').text
c
# Output: 'AusschreibungEr\xadneue\xadrung SDRL 3'
```

Usar o get_text() dá o mesmo resultado.

O que me interessa dentro do objeto b é "Er­neue­rung SDRL 3" . Como posso passar tudo para texto (' Ausschreibung Er­neue­rung SDRL 3" ou eliminar a tag 'em' dentro do b para ficar apenas com o texto "Er­neue­rung SDRL 3" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex pode ser um caminho:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url0 = 'https://www.service.bund.de/Content/DE/Ausschreibungen/Suche/Formular.html?nn=4641482&cl2Addresses_Adresse_State=nordrhein-westfalen&resultsPerPage=100'

r = requests.get(url0,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('ul', {"class": "result-list"})
links = content.find_all('a')

y = links[0]

b = y.find('h3')

# Texto que queremos remover
em_tag_text = b.find('em').get_text()

# Texto sujo, que se inicia pelo texto que queremos remover
messy_text = b.get_text()

# Limpando
clean_text = re.sub(rf"^{em_tag_text}", '', messy_text)
clean_text
```